# Rolebased authorization in WCF Hosted at Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I've a WCF service hosted at internal domain with AZMan role provider. All works great.

We would like to take the same approach of authorization in Azure as well. Could anyone please tell me whether Azman is supported in Azure. If not, what are options for ROLE BASED AUTHORIZATION WCF Services in AZURE.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Azman is not supported natively in Azure - it is heavily COM-based. You would need to use [Azure ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147631.aspx) (Access Control Services). You could tie this into your on-premise AzMan provider if you used the [Azure Service Bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee732537.aspx) Relay and created some services above AzMan.
Both the Service Bus and Access Control components are part of the [Azure AppFabric SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19925).